# Is using the same person as data observation in different time stamps a way to produce data leakage in a Machine Learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, train-test-split, data-leakage, data-snooping

Let's assume we are going to train a regression model (could be any ML tabular solution for regression. Ex.: LGBM, XGBoost, Perceptron, ...) to predict a customer profit in the next month. While setting up the ***training*** dataset, we observe that the same customer appears in the dataset 3 times like the following table:

| ID | REFERENCE_MONTH | PROFIT ON MONTH M-3 | PROFIT ON MONTH M-2 | PROFIT ON MONTH M-1 | PROFIT ON MONTH M+1 (TARGET) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022/04 | 2,00 (2022/01) | 4,56 (2022/02) | 3,12 (2022/03) | ***7,87 (2022/05)*** |
| 123 | 2022/05 | 4,56 (2022/02) | 3,12 (2022/03) | 1,02 (2022/04) | 9,85 (2022/06) |
| 123 | 2022/06 | 3,12 (2022/03) | 1,02 (2022/04) | ***7,87 (2022/05)*** | 2,64 (2022/07) |

The columns **ID** and **REFERENCE_MONTH** are just to determine the customer.

The true training variables would be **PROFIT ON MONTH M-3**, **PROFIT ON MONTH M-2** and **PROFIT ON MONTH M-1**.

Therefore, the target variable is **PROFIT ON MONTH M+1**.

My doubt is about the fact that the target variable in row number 1 is 7,87 because it refers to 2022/05, but this same value is also an independent variable for row number 3. Does this characterize a data leakage? I mean, the target variable for customer 123 in REFERENCE_MONTH = 2022/04 is inside the training dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem if all these records are in the training set.

There could be a problem if some records for the customer are in your training set and others in your test set if you want to use the model to predict profit for customers for which you have no training data. If this is the case then have a separate set of customers for training and testing to avoid any data data leakage.

I'd also suggest randomly shuffling the training data before training your model (if the package you're using doesn't do this for you), as the model may not train as well if related rows are clustered together.